# Can’t install Office 2010 on desktop

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

I just got a new Dell laptop with Office 2010, and I went to install Office on my desktop but it won’t activate.  It says the product has already been activated. I thought I could have it on both. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you almost certainly bought your Dell with an OEM version of Office 2010, which only allows you to activate it once, and only on the computer it came with. With a retail license, you can put it on both. Here is a link to the Office 2010 EULA.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&CTT=5&origin=HA101817777&id=13653

The relevant parts:

OEM: “a. One Copy per Device. The software license is permanently assigned to the device with which the software is distributed.” (there is no provision for a portable device as with the retail below)

Retail: “c. Portable Device. You may install another copy of the software on a portable device for use by the single primary user of the licensed device.”

Comment: Yup.  Retail FTW. I remember this being a big selling point for buying retail copies of Vista and 7.  I could resell those bad boys. But don't tell anyone.  Shhhh.

Comment: @surfasb Yes, retail is the way to go, imo...for businesses, volume license is even better though. SOOO much easier to keep track of.